# how to move some vertices of the same object to a desired x,y,z location?

Tags: edit-mode, vertices

so the question is:how to move selected vertices all in the same coordinate.
for example how to move 30 selected vertices in x:3.1 and y:1.5 and in the z axis not to move them.
I can't make this questions simplier i can't descibe it better D:.Please comment if u doesn't understand me.
Note:This can be done easily by selecting individual vertices and entering the desired coordinates, but it will take ages if you have many :/, so is there a better way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- **Select** vertices
- **Collapse** XY coordinates: with "Median point" pivot selected, **scale** to zero on all but Z axis by pressing <kbd>S</kbd>, than <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd>, than set the amount to <kbd>0</kbd>
- **Move** vertices to desiderd XY coordinates (you can use the Transform coordinates in the Properties panel to set precise coordinates)

Answer (score 3):

Another way is to place the 3D cursor manually via the location input fields in n-panel, 3D Cursor tab. Then select your vertices, hit <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd> (or Mesh -> Snap from the menu), and then "Selection to Cursor".

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the flatten command (<kbd>Space</kbd> then type "flatten"). In the option panel (<kbd>F6</kbd>), you can choose the axis you want to flatten on. The only downside of this tool is that it makes the face an n-gon, which may not be useful.